# How to include ascii or unicode characters in prawn documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

How does one render ascii or unicode glyphs within a PDF generated by Prawn.

For example, how would I include the glyphs U+2605 or U+2606?

Comment: If the font used in the pdf supports the character, simply using `"\u2605"` or `"\u2606"` should display the glyph.

Comment: thanks @vee, thats what I thought should happen. Though I am just getting a horizontal line. I have tried with all supported font types. Zapf Dingbats definitely supports this character. I am stumped!